# Laravel 5 flatten collection

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object resulting from this query:

```
$incaricoIndex = Incarico::with(['assicurato'])->get();
```

I have a parent table `incarico` and a related `assicurato` one; they are related by `incarico.idAssicurato` and `assicurato.id` field.

With my query I get this result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "amministratore": null,
    "blocco": null,
    "broker": null,
    "capControparte": null,
    "capSinistro": null,
    "controparte": "",
    [CUT]
    "evento": { // related table
        "tipoEvento": "Fuoco"
    }
}
```

But I would like to have this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "amministratore": null,
    "blocco": null,
    "broker": null,
    "capControparte": null,
    "capSinistro": null,
    "controparte": "",
    [CUT]
    "tipoEvento": "Fuoco"
}
```

And I need to have all the `related` data flatted at the same level of the parent object `attributes`.

Is it necessary to convert it to an array for proper manipulation or is there an helper available?

I will prefer the second case so I could maintain the `eloquent` object type..

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Can you give an example how is the data currently structured and how would you want it to be structured when flattened?

Comment: Have you tried the flatten() method on the collection? https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-flatten

Comment: Yes I tried with `$flattened = $incaricoIndex->flatten();` but `$flattened` is identical to `$incaricoIndex`

Comment: Can I ask, just out of curiosity, why is it a problem to access them trough the relation like this `$incaricoIndex->assicurato->propertyName`

Comment: @TheFallen the array is passed to datatables JavaScript library script that needs a one-level object in my actual setup. Another solution could be to pass the multilevel object with all relations, even the empty ones. Could it be possible?

Comment: You definitely need a multilevel object if this relationship is one to many, because all the properties will be overwritten by the last object. To pass it to the JS as a multilevel you can just use $incaricoIndex->toJson().